# Gazelle taillight Power Vision user manual

Tags: taillight

I have this battery-powered tail lamp. It has one button to switch on/off and, when pressed for few seconds, probably "lock" lamp, which indicates this by flashing 3 times ("unlocking" procedure is the same).

I'd like to know how to activate movement / light sensor on this lamp, in which it's probably equipped with. It has also some kind of battery level indicator, which I'm not sure how to interprete. User guide for this model would be appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gazelle Power Vision taillight has no independent manual.  As it is only sold on a bike, the manual for the bike contains the information you need.

1. You can determine if there is an automatic function built in to the light by checking the power switch. If the power switch only has 2 positions, you have a manual only light. If there are 3 positions, then the light has a sensor function.  The function you are thinking of as a lock, may be the auto function. If not, you appear to have the manual version.
2. If the sensor function is active, then the light will turn on when the bike is moving. It will remain on 1 minute after motion stops. Some models also have a light sensor, and will stay on longer in the dark.
3. The battery indicator is automatic. It will begin to flash when the light calculates 10 hours of battery life are remaining.

Comment: Didn't figured out if it is really just on/off. I've bought Axa Echo 30 Steady Auto, dynamo powered front light and it has just 2 positions of switch - 1 (permanently on) and Auto - when lamp goes into shade. (that imply 2 positions does not automatically menas there is no light- or movement- sensor). last 2 poins of your answer are usefull, so that can be marked as an answer.

Comment: While I understand your point that other lights may have 2 switch positions and still use the auto function as the "off" position, according to your manual, referenced above, the Gazelle Power vision has an off position on the light with the auto function. Thus, it has 3 positions on the model with the sensor, and 2 positions on the manual version. That said, other lights, like the Axa Echo 30, may handle the same functions with a different user interface.